# Android Dependencies broken (Eclipse). Buildpath error?

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies, android-appcompat, buildpath

**Picture of the problem**

[image]

I have cleaned my project, updated with SDK manager and created new projects, deleted and updated appcompat. Even reinstalled eclipse and my SDK.

Can't find any information on this problem which I have not tried already.

Using android 5.0 with minimum required 2.2

Any help?

Comment: delete and re-add the appcompat library

Comment: I've done it, doesn't help

Comment: Try to check if you have different versions of the same library. It may help to look at 'Problems' window

Comment: I do not have different versions. I can at least not find them, I have searched and looked at the Problems window.

Comment: Click on the appCompat library, go to Project Settings, and make sure it's linked to the correct Android Version.  There's a good chance it's not linked to any Android version..